# How to create a model angular2

Tags: angular, javascript-objects, angular2-template

I am trying to store user input in a model, which would be better organized if I could nest properties in objects, and use them in my component.

My attempted model:

```
export class carConfig {
  make: string;
  model: string;
  colors: Colors;
}

class colorDetail  {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export class Colors {
  exterior: colorDetail;
  interior: colorDetail;
  interiorTrim: colorDetail;
  roof: colorDetail;
}
```

With the following code:

```
  setSelectedColor(category: string, colorID: number, colorName: string): void {
    switch (category) {
      case 'Exterior':
        this.car.colors.exterior.id = colorID;
        this.car.colors.exterior.name = colorName;
        console.log('1');
        break;
      case 'Interior':
        this.car.colors.interior.id = colorID;
        this.car.colors.interior.name = colorName;
        console.log('2');
        break;
      case 'Interior Trim':
        this.car.colors.interiorTrim.id = colorID;
        this.car.colors.interiorTrim.name = colorName;
        console.log('3');
        break;
      case 'Roof':
        this.car.colors.roof.id = colorID;
        this.car.colors.roof.name = colorName;
        console.log('4');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

I get the following error:

`Property 'Exterior' does not exist on type 'Object'.)`

How do I go about creating a model, which represents an Object for my component to use?

Comment: What is the content of `this.car`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use angular model binding to do all of this but in the scope of your original code example the following structure would work quite well

**car.ts**

```
export interface Car {
  make: string;
  model: string;
  colors: Colors;
}

export interface Color {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface Colors {
  exterior: Color;
  interior: Color;
  interiorTrim: Color;
  roof: Color;
}

export const ColorSelectionToPropertyMap = Object.freeze({
  'Roof': 'roof',
  'Exterior': 'exterior',
  'Interior': 'interior',
  'Interior Trim': 'interiorTrim'
});
export type ColorSelectionToPropertyMap = typeof ColorSelectionToPropertyMap;

export function createCar(make?: string, model?: string): Car {
  return {
    make,
    model,
    colors: {} as Colors
  };
}
```

In consuming code

```
import {
  createCar,
  ColorSelectionToPropertyMap
} from './car';

export class CartComponent {
  car = createCar();

  setSelectedColor(
    category: keyof ColorSelectionToPropertyMap, 
    id: number,
    name: string
  ) {
    const propertyName = ColorOptions[category];
    this.car.colors[propretyName] = {
      name,
      id
    };
  }
}
```